# Powershell replace xml node values from one file to another

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-5.0

Powershell newbie here...

I have the following XML files (2).  One will have data in it and the other is just the format.  I've seen articles on replacing one item in the node but can't see to figure out a For Loop or a command to update all elements of the node.

All I have thus far is the for loop and then the action of updating one file is where I'm stuck.

Precursor: Not looking for consulting work or finish product in the end.  Just looking for some pointing places, commands etc, to guide me to the end product.

```
[xml]$File1 = Get-Content File1.xml
[xml]$File2 = Get-Content File2.xml

foreach($node in $File.CHECKLIST.ASSET.ChildNodes) {

$File2.CHECKLIST.ASSET.?LocalName?.value = $File1.CHECKLIST.ASSET.?LocalName?.value

}
```

Update...

Example of File1.xml

```
<LIST>
<ASSET>
    <ROLE>Some Role</ROLE>
    <ASSET_TYPE>Server</ASSET_TYPE>
    <HOST_NAME>My Computer</HOST_NAME>
</ASSET>
```

Example of File2.xml

```
<LIST>
<ASSET>
    <ROLE></ROLE>
    <ASSET_TYPE></ASSET_TYPE>
    <HOST_NAME></HOST_NAME>
</ASSET>
```

Desired output of File2.xml

```
    <LIST>
<ASSET>
    <ROLE>Some Role</ROLE>
    <ASSET_TYPE>Server</ASSET_TYPE>
    <HOST_NAME>My Computer</HOST_NAME>
</ASSET>
```

This is only a small portion of both files.

Comment: I'd suggest using `Import-CliXml` and `Export-CliXml` as your easiest starting points with XML and PowerShell.